# How do I get it to change back to disabled in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this [example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/rTzwB/) which works great. The buttons are disabled as default and if there is a radio button change to yes then the corresponding button is enabled. The problem is i need it to go back to disabled if they switch it back. The only time it should be enabled if the block has at least one radio button clicked yes

Comment: You could have tidied up the HTML code a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are using the same `id` for all the buttons on the page, which is a no-no. Each `id` needs to be unique.  Use a class `.make_requests` on the buttons.

Then try this out:

```
$("input:radio").change(function() {
    var wrap = $(this).parents('.accordionContent');
    var button = wrap.find('.make_requests');
    if (wrap.find('input[type=radio][value=yes]:checked').length) {
        button.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        button.attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/rTzwB/10/